# How do I configure Postgres 9.5 server so that I can access it from a remote machine?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) you have to put a line like

```
host     all             all             AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/24         md5
```

into the config file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`, where `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` is the IP address of the client machine.

The problem is that the IP address of my notebook (client machine) changes, when I connect from different networks (like office, home, mobile internet).

Is there a way to configure Postgres so that it will accept remote connections from all addresses?

Note: The server in question is an experimental one and doesn't store any sensitive information.

Comment: From documentation page that you are mention: '_0.0.0.0/0 represents all IPv4 addresses_'

Comment: Thanks. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0.0.0.0/0 represents all IPv4 addresses

From the documentation page mentioned in the question.

Also take in account that the number after the slash means the number of the significant bits, so `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/24` not the address of the client machine but the range of addresses from `AAA.BBB.CCC.0` to `AAA.BBB.CCC.255`.